# How to make a simple JSONP asynchronous request in Angular 2?

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, xmlhttprequest, angular, jsonp

I'm trying to convert the following Angular 1 code to Angular 2:

```
$http.jsonp('https://accounts.google.com/logout');
```

It needs to be a JSONP request to skip the CORS policy issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular 15's standalone component API, use [`withJsonpSupport()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/withJsonpSupport):

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient(withJsonpSupport())],
});
```

Answer (score 74):

**In the latest version of Angular**

1. Import **HttpClientModule** and **HttpClientJsonpModule** modules in your app module's definition file

   ```
    import {
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientJsonpModule
    } from '@angular/common/http';

    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
        //... List of components that you need.
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientJsonpModule,
        //...
    ],
    providers: [
        //...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
   ```
2. Inject *http* and *map* rxjs operator into your service:

   ```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class MegaSuperService {
       constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
    }
   ```
3. Make JSONP requests in the following way:

   ```
    // inside your service
    this._http.jsonp('/api/get', 'callback').map(data => {
    // Do stuff.
    });
   ```

**In Angular version 2 - version 4.3**

1. Import JSONP module in your app module's definition file:

   ```
    import {JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';

    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
        //... List of components that you need.
    ],
    imports: [
        JsonpModule,
        //...
    ],
    providers: [
        //...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
   ```
2. Inject *jsonp* service and *map* rxjs operator into your service:

   ```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class MegaSuperService {
       constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) {}
    }
   ```
3. Make requests using "JSONP_CALLBACK" as a callback property:

   ```
    // inside your service
    this._jsonp.get('/api/get?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK').map(data => {
    // Do stuff.
    });
   ```

Comment: any idea why this "exact same code" can throw a `EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: null`, never entering in the `map` function ?

Comment: I'm getting the follow error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: __ng_jsonp____req0_finished is not defined
and JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.

Any idea? 
My api call has the jsonp parameter. 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&access_token={myAccesToken}

I'm importing jsonp from angular/http and injecting in into the constructor.
Also I added to the imports in the app.module.ts file.

Comment: @MoshMage are you seeing that behavior in both IE & Chrome? Chrome is working fine for me, IE is throwing an error behind the scenes yet returning a response 200: OK to the subscription.

Comment: @GastonK is the API expecting the callback to be "JSONP_CALLBACK"? angular overwrites this with the  __ng_jsonp____req<count>_finished if it sees this exact string.  see: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13ba2f90b9551e7aa9f14e5a7e5feab3d47a9ee7/modules/%40angular/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.ts#L74

Answer (score 26):

In **Angular 4.3** and up you should use [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) because the [JsonpModule](https://angular.io/api/http/JsonpModule) is deprecated.

1. Import [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) and [HttpClientJsonpModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientJsonpModule) into your module.
2. Inject [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) into your service.
3. Pass the callback key as the second argument for the `jsonp` method.

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// Import relevant http modules
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ExampleService } from './example.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Import relevant http modules
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule
  ],
  providers: [ExampleService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`example.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// Import HttpClient class
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  // Inject HttpClient class
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    const url = "https://archive.org/index.php?output=json&callback=archive";

    // Pass the key for your callback (in this case 'callback')
    // as the second argument to the jsonp method
    return this.http.jsonp(url, 'callback');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just an addition to this answer, we need to replace 'callback' with 'JSONP_CALLBACK'.

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay I've updated the answer with your correction. Thank you!

Comment: As a data point, I found that not only was `&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` unnecessary, it broke things - but perhaps that was in a different/newer/older version of Angular; anyway, it just "knew" to add and then remove the callback info for some reason.  YMMV.

Comment: @kcrisman Good catch! Looking at [line 1124 of the HttpClient](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bf6a416bce99d16130655cd6f833866ea0c4fe6c/packages/common/http/src/client.ts) `JSONP_CALLBACK` is appended to the callback parameter. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Now there is a new issue. Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

Comment: This has changed little over time. However, 3rd-parties may have their own name for the callback parameter, that second argument to http.jsonp. I have seen 'callback' or 'c' most commonly. And so in the url in this answer, `&callback=archive` doesn't need to exist. Angular will add that parameter you name to the passed url, such as `&callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0`.

The actual callback function should be the success function of the http.jsonp Observable. This extra bit helped me to deal with Pardot form submissions.

Answer (score 10):

If this endpoint is jsonp-compliant, you can use the following. You need to find out the parameter to use to provide the jsonp callback. In the code below, I call it `c`.

After having registered `JSONP_PROVIDERS` when calling the `bootstrap` function:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ JSONP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

You can then execute your request using an instance of the `Jsonp` class you injected from constructor:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Jsonp} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      Result: {{result | json}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(jsonp:Jsonp) {
    var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/logout&c=JSONP_CALLBACK';
    jsonp.request(url, { method: 'Get' })
     .subscribe((res) => {
       (...)
     });
  }
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [I need to do a http request to a mail chimp subscription list via a component post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180562/i-need-to-do-a-http-request-to-a-mail-chimp-subscription-list-via-a-component-po/35181085#35181085)