# Http get request in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jsonp, ionic2

I am trying to retrieve data from the Statbureau inflation api- https://www.statbureau.org/en/inflation-api using Angular 2. I am starting off just testing out my api and making sure it outputs a success message in the console. It appears that the api I'm using is JSONP, because of the JSON address that I'm using **http://www.statbureau.org/calculate-inflation-price-jsonp?jsoncallback=?** On the website they provide a JS fiddle that makes a succesful call to the api using jquery. When I try to make the same call in Angular 2 I get the following errors:

```
TypeScript error: C:/Users/Rennie/projects/inflator/app/pages/home/home.ts(22,13): Error TS
2322: Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'HomePage'.
  Property 'jsonp' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.
TypeScript error: C:/Users/Rennie/projects/inflator/app/pages/home/home.ts(22,13): Error TS
2409: Return type of constructor signature must be assignable to the instance type of the c
```

**Here is my code**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Jsonp, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {

    this.jsonp=jsonp;
        let cpiUrl = "https://www.statbureau.org/calculate-inflation-price-jsonp?jsoncallback"
         let params = new URLSearchParams();
      params.set('country', 'united-states');
      params.set('amount', '102');
        params.set('start', '1968/1/1');
        params.set('finish', '2016/1/1');
        // TODO: Add error handling
        return this.jsonp
               .get(cpiUrl, { search: params }).map(function(response){ return response.json(); })

    }


}
```

My code differs from the call in the jsfiddle because I hard coded the api parameters just to quickly see a result.

Answer (score 1):

1) A constructor typically (always?) does not have a return statement. Removing the return statment should handle `type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'HomePage'.`

2) There does not seem to be a method `get` on the `Jsonp` class in `Angular 2` check the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Jsonp-class.html).

3) An observable sequence/pipeline will not be executed until subscription (they are lazy), so even if that code did compile the request would not be executed.

4) I think you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2) similiar question.

Good luck.

Comment: I reposted this because of a new error, take a look- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401935/jsonp-request-error-angular-2