# Jsonp example in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, jsonp, laravel-5.3

I am looking for an example in angular 2 about **Jsonp**. I follow this tutorial [angular server communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) to create server communication. But i can't connect my Laravel 5.3 api via ***Http***, there need ***jsonp***. But there is not a good example about *jsonp*.

So please help me to get a good example about **jsonp**. Thanks.

Comment: share your code so that i could see what is the problem .Here is another reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer - hey, this question not duplicate, did you check angular.io documentation? your provided answer not like that documentation. I tried many times and failed, for that reason, i asked