# Angular 2 Http with jsonp

Tags: angular

I would like to know what's the appropriate method for perfoming a JSONP get call. In this instance, my JSONP url is listed under `myRun` as you can [see in this link](http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myRun).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
constructor(private http: Http){}
    fetchData(){
    return this.http.get('http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myRun').map(
        (res) => res.json()
        ).subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data)
    );
    }
}
```

I've seen [examples that use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2) `JSONP_PROVIDERS`, but I believe they are deprecated by now. Thus, I am wondering what the up-to-date method is for making a JSONP get request.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still the same thing as in the examples you linked to. But instead of using the `JSONP_PROVIDERS`, you import the `JsonpModule` just like you would the `HttpModule`. Then just inject `Jsonp`, like in [your linked example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36289568/2587435). It's usage hasn't changed.

> ```
> export class AppComponent {
>   constructor(jsonp:Jsonp) {
>     var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/logout&c=JSONP_CALLBACK';
>     jsonp.request(url, { method: 'Get' })
>      .subscribe((res) => {
>        (...)
>      });
>   }
> }
> ```

All of the previously mentioned classes can be also imported from `@angular/http`.