# Angular 2: JSONP request giving EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL

Tags: angular, jsonp

I am trying to make a JSONP call using Angular 2 and followed everything mentioned in this post: [How to make a simple JSONP asynchronous request in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2)

Here is my **service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Jsonp } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataLoadService {
    private quoteApiUrl: string;
    constructor(private http: Http, private jsonp: Jsonp) { 
                    this.quoteApiUrl = `http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&jsonp=parseQuote&lang=en&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;
                }

    getQuotes(): Observable<any>{
        return this.jsonp.get(this.quoteApiUrl)
            .map(function(res){
                return res.json() || {};
            })
            .catch(function(error: any){
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
    }
}
```

And this is how I am calling my **getQuotes()** method from my **home.ts**:

```
 this.dataLoadService.getQuotes()
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.quotes.push(data);
      });
```

This being a JSONP call, I have added: `&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` at the end of my API.

When the service is invoked, I do get valid JSON response as in Chrome's Developer Tools > Network > Response tab:

```
parseQuote({"quoteText":"A failure is a man who has blundered but is not capable of cashing in on the experience. ", "quoteAuthor":"Elbert Hubbard", "senderName":"", "senderLink":"", "quoteLink":"http://forismatic.com/en/d74d7833cb/"})
```

But I also get the following errors:

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: parseQuote is not defined
2. EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL:
   [http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&jsonp=parseQuote&lang=en&parseQuote=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished](http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&jsonp=parseQuote&lang=en&parseQuote=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished)

Please advise. I am using angular v2.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, the issue is with the api endpoint url that you are providing. Apparently it does not take the callback function name in the `callback` parameter but in `jsonp` parameter.

Replace your url with this one and it should work fine: `http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&jsonp=JSONP_CALLBACK&lang=en`

Comment: Thanks Obaid. Your suggestion worked. May I ask how did you know that the callback function name needs to come in jsonp paramter and not callback parameter. Is there anything is the error which tells you this. If you can share this, it will help me in similar scenarios in future.