# JSONP request - Angular 2 error

Tags: angular, jsonp, instagram-api

I'm trying to make a jsonp request to the instagram API with Angular 2 but I'm getting "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback"

I followed this [How to make a simple JSONP asynchronous request in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2) and also the official doc of angular 2 but can't make it work.

```
fetch() {
  return this._jsonp.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&access_token={token}')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Jsonp is injected in the constructor and imported in the service, and in the app.module.ts as well.
I tried callback=JSONP_CALLBACK, c=JSONP_CALLBACK and jsonp=JSONP_CALLBACK but none of them work.

If I make it via postman it works.

Comment: Please check which @angular/http version you are using. There is bug in version http - 2.4.7. If this is the case then downgrade it to http - 2.4.5.

Comment: btw, related issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14267