# Refused to execute script from URL because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: angular, google-chrome, jsonp

I am trying to retrieve contacts from Google within an Angular 4 Universal app.

But I receive this error message once authentication has been done:

> Refused to execute script from
>   https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=TOKEN&alt=json
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and
>   strict MIME type checking is enabled.

At the moment everything is held in one Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'refer-friend',
  templateUrl: './referFriend.component.html',
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth();
  }
  auth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      'client_id': 'CLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
    }, () => {
      this.fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());  
    });
  }
  fetch(token: any) {
    this.jsonp.get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=' + token.access_token + '&alt=json')
     .map(data => {
        return data;
     })
     .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
     });
  }
}
```

I got the code [from this sample](https://gist.github.com/lupeke/6233678) which works fine without this error happening. So I can only guess Angular is effecting something....

Comment: Are you sure it's not a duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2

Comment: You would not return data in a map either. It's usually used to do things like convert a Response https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html to a json payload - Response contains HTTP headers etc. so map(response:Response => responce.json()). You should also refactor that into a service an return it as an Observable. Ideally of an interface or domain model class. I see you're subscribing to a feed. The component should then inject that service annotated with @ Injectable as a private param in the component constructor, & be wired into @ ngModule providers:[] of your app-module.ts

Comment: then the component becomes... this.service.subscribe(data => this.data = data);

Comment: I was trying to determine the payload from here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ - FYI when you define an interface you can use ? to represent optional properties. See here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Contacts API documentation has a link to how the alt tag works. The value 'json' does not indicate that it will return JSONP data. Google returns that MIME type because the data it will give you is not executable.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference

Try using the `@angular/http` standard get method instead of `Jsonp`.

Comment: You were right, thank you! I guess I got confused with the example I based it on because that was using JSONP for the AJAX call.