# adding api username and password to a HTTP.Get request

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have been going trough this problem since yesterday, and while I have been searching through StackOverflow and other forums I couldn't find an answer to that problem.

I am looking to call a JSON array from our company's API, I was trying this code but it didn't work.

```
constructor(public http: Http) {
  console.log('Data Service connected...');
}

getPosts() {
  const url = 'example.com';
  const header = new Headers();
  header.set('user', 'foo');
  header.append('password', 'bar');
  header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  const options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});
  return this.http.get(url, options).map(res => res.json());
}
```

However when I try to compile I get an error 401 (Unauthorized), is there any way to input the username and the password to get the response from the API?

**EDIT**

Here are the request headers:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type,password,user
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:ess.gtslb.com
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Are you able to call your api using a rest client? try to use a rest client(postman...) to understand what headers to set!

Comment: to be honest I didn't get what you said

Comment: I see your problem is solved!

Comment: yes denis gave me a good answer it helped me get through the first barrier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be great to see the response header, have you tried to use [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2)?
My guess you query a different server, and in this case you can't use a simple ajax call.

Comment: I am calling the api from the company's server to my local machine here I will update the question to add the request headers