# How to get json using a jsonp request

Tags: javascript, json, angular, instagram-api, ionic3

I'm trying to use instagrams api, without having to authenticate.
if I go to: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/chicago/?__a=1

I get a json response.
I'm trying to build an angular 4 provider that returns that data.

```
getInsta(term){
    return this.jsonp.request(this.url+term+'/?__a=1&callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished')
      .map(res => {
        console.log(res.json());
      });
  }
```

I've tried "callback" and "c". I've tried JSONP_CALLBACK.

I get the error of:

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. - In chicago:1"

and

> "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback"

If I click on the unexpected token error, it brings me to the response with all the json data in it. So that means it's coming through, I just cant access it!

Any idea how i can get around this?

Here is a screenshot of the error and when clicking on the error
[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly response do you have?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav in terms of what? I get the 2 errors i listed above, if I click on the token error and look at what line the actual error is on, it brings me to the jsonp script which has the exact data in it as if you were to visit the url on your browser.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40027481/6611700) should help... the answer is for Angular 2 but much of it should apply to Angular 4 as well

Answer (score 2):

JSONP is a method to fetch data cross origin, it works because it injects a `script` tag to the body when the `src` of the file contains the `callback` function name.

```
<script src="http://ani.site.com/api/?callback=myGlobalFunc">
```

And it assumes that there is a global func on the window with the name `myGlobalFunc`.

The response of that call gonna look like: `myGlobalFunc({data: 'data1'})`.
Invocation of the function with one argument which is the data.

In your case, Instagram API return **JSON** not `JSONP`.

There for you can't use that mechanism.

Comment: @pritambanerjee Please look at my updated question. I understand the difference between json and jsonp, but the data is actually coming through, i just cant use it inside my app.

Comment: Ok, now it looks like u fetched via jsonp, but Instagram is returning json, align your request method to the actual response type.

Comment: this is the error im getting now: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/chicago/?__a=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Ok, so as I said JSONP was invented in order to overcome Cross origin, so just use it.