# Angular 5: callbackParam doesn't work in JSONP request using HTTPClient

Tags: angular, httpclient, jsonp, angular5

I think HTTPClient jsonp method's second parameter doesn't work as expected or I may not be understanding it correctly. [Link](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#jsonp)

Below are the things I have done to use jsonp:

I have imported **HttpClientJsonpModule** in app.module.ts
Below is the code of it

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ConstituencyStatusService } from './constituency-status.service';
import { SwitcherService } from './switcher.service'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   HttpClientJsonpModule
  ],
  providers: [ConstituencyStatusService,SwitcherService,],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

then I am trying to do the following but getting the error

```
this.http.jsonp(url,'test_callback').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

error is ReferenceError: test_callback is not defined

My JSON output is URL is : goo.gl/6fqXq5

```
test_callback({ "test_url_1": "url_1", "test_url_2": "url_2", "test_url_3": "url_3", "test_url_4": "url_4", "test_url_5": "url_5", "test_url_6": "url_6", "test_url_7": "url_7" })
```

I see in network tab that httpclient is adding *?test_callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0* after the url

Then after some debugging I tried this json return: goo.gl/cUwx93

```
ng_jsonp_callback_0({ "test_url_1": "url_1", "test_url_2": "url_2", "test_url_3": "url_3", "test_url_4": "url_4", "test_url_5": "url_5", "test_url_6": "url_6", "test_url_7": "url_7" })
```

and it worked.

Can somebody explain why it worked now and how can I pass my custom callback function name to jsonp in Angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you show the `url` you're passing to `jsonp()`?

As [noticed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47643846/2724204) (kcrisman comment), it looks like you're not the only one encountering a such issue.

If you're specifying the callback name as `queryParam` in your request, it broke things. Not specifying it and only add the callback name to `jsonp()` method seems to work.

You also can check the [line N°1124 of HttpClient](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bf6a416bce99d16130655cd6f833866ea0c4fe6c/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L1124) to see its behavior with `JSONP_CALLBACK`.

Comment: URL with my callback name: goo.gl/6fqXq5 URL with ng_jsonp_callback_0 name: goo.gl/cUwx93

Comment: I tried `jsonp()` without `queryParam` and have also specified name in `jsonp()` only. Still same error.

Comment: Damn. Can you please reproduce your issue in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) please? It generally helps.

Comment: @Pankaj - did you found solution?