# HERE Geocoder API CORS support

Tags: cors, here-api, angular-httpclient

I am using **Angular 8 HttpClient** to make a **GET** request to the **HERE Geocoder API**. But the request is blocked by the browser due to failed **CORS preflight** request.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=[APP_ID]&app_code=[APP_CODE]&country=hkg&language=en-GB&searchtext=royal%20view%20hotel'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4201' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

(My actual **app id** and **app code** have been substituted with [APP_ID] and [APP_CODE] in the above message for obvious reasons)

From what I understand (after reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), the **preflight request** is sent as an **OPTIONS** request by the browser. And the browser has failed the (preflight) response from the **HERE API server** and so blocking the original GET request.

Could this be an issue with the HERE API server responding incorrectly to the **preflight OPTIONS request**?
If so, would anyone suggest a good way to simulate the preflight request to check the response from HERE API?

**UPDATE - simulating preflight request**

I tried to simulate a **preflight** request from Postman to see what HERE API server was responding with.

Request details are as follows.
Request type: **OPTIONS**
Url: **https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json**
Header params:

> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with
>   Origin: http://localhost:4201

Response for the above request.
Status: **404**
Response body:

```
<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Errors/1" type="PermissionError" subtype="InvalidCredentials">
    <Details>invalid credentials for </Details>
</ns2:Error>
```

If I tried to include the query parameters into the URL (to include the app_id, and app_code) like so:
**https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&app_code=YYYYYYYYYY&country=hkg&language=en-GB&searchtext=royal view hotel**

The same error status is returned (404). And the response body looks like this:

```
<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Errors/1" type="PermissionError" subtype="InvalidCredentials">
    <Details>invalid credentials for XXXXXXXXXXXXX</Details>
</ns2:Error>
```

where XXXXXXXXXXXXX is my **app_id** parameter value. Obviously this value was substituted for my actual app_id, which is valid and returns results when run from Postman in a normal GET request.

Unless I am missing something in simulating the preflight request, then it would appear the HERE API server is not responding correctly to the preflight.

I would be grateful for any help and suggestions.

Comment: The API can be tested correctly for response code in POSTMAN if only response needs to be tested correctly. It's the browser measure for security at your end, which can be disabled. CORS can be enabled (by setting proxy server)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I have updated my questions, and only just saw your comment. Do you know if the HERE api server responds correctly to the preflight OPTIONS request issued by the browser?

Answer (score 1):

In general the HERE Geocoder API does not support OPTIONS method , however it should be possible to use the jsonp approach for the CORS issue. Pretty sure Angular has some libraries which support jsonp, an approach is described in this thread: [How to make a simple JSONP asynchronous request in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2)